# How return join result between two tables with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 tables `sdr` and `operator`.

sdr:

```
id duration dialednum description
0   666      1234      text
1   777      5678      text
2   888      1234      text
```

operator:

```
id name   avaya_id description
0  smitt    1234    text
1  bill     5678    text
```

And I need select this tables and insert result to another table - `calls`

cals:

```
id duration operator_id
0   666      0
1   777      1
2   888      0
```

I need select two tables `sdr` and `operator` and insert result(after some manipulations with data) to `cals` table.

I use JPA and I do not understand how to do it. I have one idea to create another class like `SdrOperator` and write:

```
private List<SdrOperator> getAllModelsIterable(int offset, int max) {
        List<SdrOperator> resultList = null;
        try {
            resultList = em.createQuery(" SELECT m.id, m.duration, m.dialednum, m.description, o.id from Cdr m, Operators o WHERE m.codedial = o.avaya_id", SdrOperator.class).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(max).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

And after that create `Cals class` from `SdrOperator.class` or There is another solution?

Comment: I am a lazy bugger, so I would create a view, then use Eclipse to generate an Entity based upon that View

Comment: I was a little did not understand you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.

1) Use **@JoinTable** strategy. In this case you don't need to create association class (eg. SdrOperator). See sample

```
@Entity
public class Sdr{
   @Id
   @Column(name="ID")
   private long id;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name="cals",
          joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="duration", referencedColumnName="duration")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="operator_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
   private List<Operator> operators;

}
```

2) Create an association class as you mention likes SdrOperator and join with Sdr and Operator classes. Check an example and explanation from this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany).